# Can't get urls after upload files to firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

i have small app that upload images to firebase and get urls to display them. When i upload single image it work well. but when i tried upload multiple images it not work as i thought. It alway return emty array, i want somthing like [url1,url2,...]. Here my code:
firebase

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ,
  authDomain: ,
  projectId: ,
  storageBucket: ,
  messagingSenderId: ,
  appId: ,
  measurementId: 
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const storage = getStorage(app);

myApp

        import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { storage } from "../../ultis/firebase";
import { ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from "firebase/storage";

const MyApp= () => {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);
  const [urls, setUrls] = useState([]);
  const [percs, setPercs] = useState(0);

    const uploadFile = async () => {
      await Promise.all(
        files.map((f, i) => {
          const name = new Date().getTime() + f.name;
          const storageRef = ref(
            storage,
            `images/products/${name}`
          );
          const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, f);

          uploadTask.on(
            "state_changed",
            (snapshot) => {},
            (error) => {},
            () => {
              getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
                setUrls((prev) => [...prev, downloadURL]);
              });
            }
          );
        })
      );
      console.log(urls); <-- it not works, return [], i want upload files after user click a button
    };
  console.log(urls); <-- it works, return [url1,url2,...]

  return (
    <div className="p-3"></div>

};

export default MyApp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since an `uploadTask` behaves like a Promise, and resolves with its snapshot data when the upload completes, the following should do the trick (untested):

```
const uploadFile = async () => {
  await Promise.all(
    files.map((f, i) => {
      const name = new Date().getTime() + f.name;
      const storageRef = ref(
        storage,
        `images/products/${name}`
      );
      uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, f)
      .then(snapshot => {
          return getDownloadURL(storageRef);
      })
      .then((downloadURL) => {
          setUrls((prev) => [...prev, downloadURL]);
       });

    });
  );
};
```

Another approach would be to first get the entire array of URLs and then set the URLs:

```js
  const urlsArray = await Promise.all(
    files.map((f, i) => {
      const name = new Date().getTime() + f.name;
      const storageRef = ref(
        storage,
        `images/products/${name}`
      );
      uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, f)
      .then(snapshot => {
          return getDownloadURL(storageRef);
      });
    });
  );
  // Then set the URLs
```

Comment: Hello @JackForez, did you have the time to look at my answer?